# Docker error while creating container from application image over base image

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I have created a docker base image with my dependencies needed to run my application like Java, Python, VC++ and dotnet. On top of the base image, I am creating another docker image(application image) which copies my application(asp.net core Web API) so that it runs my API from browser. In this process when I am trying to create a container on top of my application image, I am getting the following error:

```
>docker run -d -p 4000:80 --name newappcontainer6 newappimage:6.0
eec248d2f4e9b3aac693382a293f950f0458d0d3ae49030fd558a95c0ee45adc
docker: Error response from daemon: container eec248d2f4e9b3aac693382a293f950f0458d0d3ae49030fd558a95c0ee45adc encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6E59A9FAB: (caller: 00007FF6E595E19A) Exception(2) tid(398) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

I am not sure why this error is coming as my two images got created without any issues and if I checked in my images I see all my dependencies got installed properly and my app code copied inside the image.

Below are the two docker file contents which I am trying to run:

Base Image Dockerfile code:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019-amd64 AS installer
#install vc++
COPY VC_redist.x64.exe .
RUN c:\VC_redist.x64.exe /install /passive /norestart /log out.txt

#install Python
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR C:/temp/Python
#RUN New-Item C:/temp -ItemType Directory; New-Item C:/data -ItemType Directory;


ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.10.4
ENV PYTHON_RELEASE 3.10.4

RUN $url = ('https://www.python.org/ftp/python/{0}/python-{1}-amd64.exe' -f $env:PYTHON_RELEASE, $env:PYTHON_VERSION); \
    Write-Host ('Downloading {0} ...' -f $url); \
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile 'python.exe'; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Installing ...'; \
# https://docs.python.org/3.10.4/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui
    Start-Process python.exe -Wait \
        -ArgumentList @( \
            '/quiet', \
            'InstallAllUsers=1', \
            'TargetDir=C:\Python310', \
            'PrependPath=1', \
            'Shortcuts=0', \
            'Include_doc=0', \
            'Include_pip=0', \
            'Include_test=0' \
        ); \
    \
#the installer updated PATH, so we should refresh our local value
    $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
    \
    Write-Host 'Verifying install ...'; \
    Write-Host '  python --version'; python --version; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Removing ...'; \
    Remove-Item python.exe -Force; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Complete.'

# https://github.com/pypa/get-pip
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/d59197a3c169cef378a22428a3fa99d33e080a5d/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 421ac1d44c0cf9730a088e337867d974b91bdce4ea2636099275071878cc189e



RUN Write-Host ('Downloading get-pip.py ({0}) ...' -f $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL); \
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL -OutFile 'get-pip.py'; \
    Write-Host ('Verifying sha256 ({0}) ...' -f $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256); \
    if ((Get-FileHash 'get-pip.py' -Algorithm sha256).Hash -ne $env:PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256) { \
        Write-Host 'FAILED!'; \
        exit 1; \
    }; \
    \
    Write-Host ('Installing pip ...'); \
    python get-pip.py \
        --disable-pip-version-check \
        --no-cache-dir \
    ; \
    Remove-Item get-pip.py -Force; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Verifying pip install ...'; \
    pip --version; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Complete.'

#install Java
MAINTAINER Zulu Enterprise Container Images <azul-zulu-images@microsoft.com>


RUN setx PACKAGE zulu-8-azure-jdk_8.58.0.13-8.0.312-win_x64.msi
RUN setx PACKAGE_DIR zulu-8/8u312
RUN setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\temp\Zulu\zulu-8"
RUN setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\temp\Zulu\zulu-8\bin"

RUN powershell -Command [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://repos.azul.com/azure-only/zulu/packages/zulu-8/8u312/zulu-8-azure-jdk_8.58.0.13-8.0.312-win_x64.msi', 'C:\%PACKAGE%')
RUN msiexec /quiet /i C:\%PACKAGE% 
RUN del C:\%PACKAGE%
    
RUN setx PACKAGE zulu-8-azure-jre_8.58.0.13-8.0.312-win_x64.msi
RUN setx PACKAGE_DIR zulu-8/8u312
RUN setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\temp\zulu-8-jre"
RUN setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\temp\zulu-8-jre\bin"


RUN powershell -Command [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://repos.azul.com/azure-only/zulu/packages/zulu-8/8u312/zulu-8-azure-jre_8.58.0.13-8.0.312-win_x64.msi', 'C:\%PACKAGE%')
RUN msiexec /quiet /i C:\%PACKAGE%
RUN del C:\%PACKAGE%

RUN powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1; ./dotnet-install.ps1 -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet' -Channel 6.0 -Runtime dotnet; 
RUN Remove-Item -Force dotnet-install.ps1
#RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\dotnet"
```

Image which I created for my Web API on top of the above base image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build-env
WORKDIR /Program Files/dotnet
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM newbaseimage:5.0 as runtime
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as runtime
#FROM newbaseimage:5.0 as installer
WORKDIR /Program Files/dotnet
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
#COPY VC_redist.x64.exe .

#RUN VC_redist.x64.exe /install /passive /norestart /log out.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDesignStudioAPI.dll"]

#Environment variables to connect to Azure
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID=6baec3cf-e284-4db8-8576-5af4320f3849 \
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=LOm8Q~UM7fQDLFSsuvgnzv9wsTE2zFtsQAa4WbjQ \
    AZURE_TENANT_ID=0fe67bdb-a749-4082-a35f-fa9f9579a348
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?